# Distribution of truncation

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous positive random variable and $a>0$ a real number, and let $I$ be the indicator function. How can I find the probability density function of $X I(X<a)$?
Does it has [this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)? How to show that?

**My attempt** Looking at $P(X\leq w|X<a)$ I can see that

(a) If $\{X\leq w\}\subseteq \{X<a\}$, then $P(X\leq w|X<a)=\frac{P((X\leq w,X<a)}{P(X<a)}=\frac{P(X\leq w)}{P(X<a)}$;

(b) If $\{X\leq w\}\supset \{X<a\}$, then $P(X\leq w|X<a)=\frac{P((X\leq w,X<a)}{P(X<a)}=1$.

These results seem to imply (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) that

(c) If $w< a$, then $f_{X|X<a}(w)=\frac{f_X(w)}{F_X(a)}$;

(d) If $w\geq a$, then $f_{X|X<a}(w)=0$.

That is $f_{X|X<a}(w)=\frac{f_X(w) I(w< a)}{F_X(a)}$.

I still don't understant how can I start from $P(X I(X<a)\leq w)$ to end with $P(X\leq w|X<a)$.

Comment: @Localth Do you know how to show it? I started writting $P(X I(X<a)\leq w)$, but couldn't get an expression like $P(X \leq w| X<a)/P(X<a)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y := XI(X < a)$. Note that $P(Y=0) \ge P(X \ge a)$ which can be strictly positive. So $Y$ may not even have a density.

Concretely, the CDF of $Y$ is
\begin{align}
P(X I(X<a) \le t)
&= P(XI(X<a) \le t \mid X < a)P(X< a) + P(XI(X<a) \le t \mid X \ge a) P(X \ge a)
\\
&= P(X \le t, X < a) + I(t \ge 0) P(X \ge a)
\\
&=
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0
\\
P(X \le t) + P(X \ge a) & 0 \le t < a\\
\\
1 & t \ge a
\end{cases}\end{align}
which has a jump at $t=0$ as long as $P(X \ge a) > 0$.

---

Note that $XI(X<a)$ is not typically called a truncation. Truncating $X$ to $[0, a)$ is usually defined by the CDF $F_Z(t) = \frac{P(0 < X \le t)}{P(0 < X \le a)} =\frac{F_X(t)-F_X(0)}{F_X(a)-F_X(0)}$ for $0 < t < a$.